# constructor invocation mechanism

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, most-vexing-parse

```
struct my
{
   my(){ std::cout<<"Default";}
   my(const my& m){ std::cout<<"Copy";}
   ~my(){ std::cout<<"Destructor";}
};

int main()
{
   my m(); //1
   my n(my()); //2
}
```

Expected output :

```
1 ) Default
2 ) Copy
```

Actual output :

---

What's wrong with my understanding of the constructor invoking mechanism?

`Note` I have omitted header files for brevity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Case 1)

`m` is interpreted as a function return `my` and taking no arguments.
To see the expected output remove `()` i.e use `my m;`

Case 2)

This is something better known as the "Most vexing parse".

`n` is interpreted as a function returning `my` that takes an argument of type pointer to function returning `my` taking no arguments.

To see the expected output in this case try `my n((my()));` [Instead of treating as an argument specification as in the former case the compiler would now interpret it as an expression because of the extra `()`]

**My interpretation:**

`my n((my()))` is equivalent to `my n = my()`. Now the rvalue expression `my()` creates a temporary[i.e a call to the default constructor] and `n` is copy initialized to that temporary object[no call to the copy-ctor because of some [compiler optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286301/why-isnt-the-copy-constructor-called-here/4286330#4286330)]

**P.S**: I am not 100% sure about the last part of my answer. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's not called RVO, but it's indeed a common optimization.

Comment: @MSalters : Yes, I think this one is a variant of RVO. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Prasoon, I suspect the C++ compiler is parsing your code in a way you don't expect.  For example, I think it is parsing the line

```
my m();
```

as a function prototype declaration, not as a variable declaration and call to the constructor - hence why you see no output.