# Why is copy-constructor not called in this case?

Tags: c++

I encountered a code snippet and thought that it would call copy-constructor but in contrast , it simply called normal constructor . Below is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B
{
    public:    
    B(const char* str = "\0")
    {
        cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
    }    
    B(const B &b)
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
    } 
};
int main()
{  
    B ob = "copy me"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: Why would you even expect it to call the copy constructor at all? `"copy me"` is a `const char [8]`, and not a `B`...

Comment: @H2CO3 because it's copy initialization. It should theoretically call it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Not even close.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl no, it's not. copy & direct initialization are different.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Why is it copy initialization?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Incorrect. That's only true if `a` and `b` have the same type. Otherwise, these two forms of initialization are not the same. In the OP's case the types are not the same.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what do you mean?

Comment: @Luchian: In order for that question to be a duplicate, it would have to be more or less in the form "Why is the wrong copy constructor being called?"

Comment: I would recommend to use one default constructor and one constructor with one arguemnt and declare that `explicit`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore i know i confused it with (f) http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm in your corner on this. The compiler may not actually generate the "call", but as you have pointed out to me in a prior question by me some time ago (seems forever ago) the standard supports creating a temp `B` from "copy me", then firing the class copy-ctor. I remember this only because in my case the compiler yelled at me for not providing a copy-ctor that it then proceeded to not call anyway, but had to be provided to be standard compliant. I'd have to search to find my old question, but I think you pointed me to the same link at the top of these comments.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but I didn't mark it as a dupe, I was merely providing a source. :) I didn't vote to close.

Comment: I thought a temporary was created here and then copied but it seems that copy epsilon is probably an optimization technique by the compiler .

Comment: @KavishDwivedi Using g++, if you compile with the `-fno-elide-constructors` switch, you'll see a call to the copy constructor. Otherwise, pretty much every compiler will elide that copy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292021/no-call-to-the-copy-constructor better? Now it is your turn, my close vote is gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you've discovered that `B ob = "copy me";` *notionally* creates a `B` from the literal and then copy constructs `ob`, but that the compiler is allowed to elide the copy and construct directory into `ob`. g++ even elides the copy with no optimization enabled at all.

You can observe that this is the case by making your copy constructor private: The code will fail to compile even though the compiler won't actually use the copy constructor (the standard requires that copy constructors be accessible even when the call is elided).

Comment: +1 the second paragraph is also notable for VC++ (at least through 2010). It behaves the same way, as i discovered, and eluded to in my comment in the general section above.

Comment: yeah , 2nd paragraph about declaring it private pretty much explains everything

Comment: Note: you can disable copy elision in g++ with the `-fno-elide-constructors` option. (Edit: I hadn't seen [Praetorian's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552785/why-is-copy-constructor-not-called-in-this-case#comment25532859_17552785)...)

Comment: eluded != alluded @WhozCraig

Comment: @bames53 lol. hate when that happens. I'm always doing it too. thanks!.