# Cannot access vector when constructing with istream_iterator range

Tags: c++, stl, most-vexing-parse

I tried to compile this code snippet but I got compiler error :( ! Compile with Visual Studio 2010

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s( "Well well on" );
    istringstream in( s );
    vector<string> v( istream_iterator<string>( in ), istream_iterator<string>() );
    copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>( cout, "\n" ) );
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   1   error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union  c:\visual studio 2008 projects\vector test\vector test\main.cpp 13  vector test
Error   2   error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union    c:\visual studio 2008 projects\vector test\vector test\main.cpp 13  vector test
```

What happened? vector was constructed correctly, how could I not be able to call it?

Best regards,

Comment: You should check out the "The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list, "Effective STL" especially

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this

```
vector<string> v( istream_iterator<string>( in ), istream_iterator<string>() );
```

is parsed as a function declaration:

```
vector<string> v( istream_iterator<string> in, istream_iterator<string> );
```

This is usually called ["C++' most-vexing parse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283576/constructor-invocation-mechanism).

I think a few extra parentheses will cure this:

```
vector<string> v( (istream_iterator<string>(in)), (istream_iterator<string>()) );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sbi, problem solved ^^! The "most vexing parse", I will remember this name!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the so-called [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).  It;'s a gotcha that stings many C++ programmers.

Basically, this code doesn't mean what you think it means:

```
vector<string> v( istream_iterator<string>( in ), istream_iterator<string>() );
```

Instead of declaring a variable of type `vector<string>`, you are actually declaring a *function* named `v` that returns `vector<string>`.

To fix this, use `operator=` like this:

```
vector<string> v = vector<string>( istream_iterator<string>( in ), istream_iterator<string>() );
```

Comment: Thanks John, I really like your solution ;)

Comment: @Chan:  Thanks.  There are a variety of ways to fix this problem.  You've seen three here.

Comment: I really could not think of any other solution from the top of my head. C++ is most the complex language that I've learned :( !

Answer (score 0):

The parser thinks the following line is declaring a function:

```
vector<string> v( istream_iterator<string>( in ), istream_iterator<string>() );
```

Change your main to this and it will compile:

```
int main() 
{
    string s( "Well well on" );
    istringstream in( s );
    istream_iterator<string> start = istream_iterator<string>(in);
    vector<string> v(start, istream_iterator<string>());
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zac for another solution ;)