# Difference between declaring a C++ object with/without braces

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [constructor invocation mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283576/constructor-invocation-mechanism)

It took me long to figure this problem. So I was curious to know the difference between them. Below is the code snippet:

```
struct Test
{
  Test () { cout<<" Test()\n"; }
 ~Test () { cout<<"~Test()\n"; }
};
int main()
{
  Test obj(); // Remove braces of 'obj' & constructor/destructor are printed
}
```

Wanted to know that, why such behavior ? Is there any fundamental difference between declaring an object with/without empty braces (here we talk only about the cases of default constructor). Code is compiled one of the latest versions of Ubuntu/g++. Sorry if, it's a repeat question.

Comment: This is a dupe! Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283576/constructor-invocation-mechanism/)

Comment: Just as an aside, *braces* are `{}`, but *parentheses* are `()`. I couldn't figure out what you meant until I realised that you were talking about the `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Test obj();
```

declares a function named `obj` that takes no parameters and returns an object of type `Test`. It does not create an object `obj` of type `Test` with the default constructor.

Comment: Oh.. thanks. I forgot that fundamental. I kept empty braces to emphasize that, this is indeed a default constructor to the viewer. But messed up with another (forward declaration) feature. :)
I usually do this, with operator 'new Struct()', but missed that, we can't do it with stack objects.

Comment: @prasoon, yes I see. Will try for it.

Answer (score 0):

`Test obj();`  means that declaring a function named `obj()` whose return type is `Test`. Statement is not actually instantiating class `Test`. For the class to be instantiated -

```
Test obj ; // obj is instantiated meaning it's constructor is called and 
           // destructor is called when gone out of scope.
```