# Why can this code elide a copy?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [constructor invocation mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283576/constructor-invocation-mechanism)
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

Why can this [code](http://ideone.com/EogJD) elide all copies of A?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  A() {}
  A(const A&) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
};

class B
{
public:
  B(const A& a_) : a(a_) {}
private:
  A a;
};

int main()
{
  B b(A());
}
```

This code apparently makes no copies of `A`, and outputs nothing under gcc 3.4 at ideone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not copy elision, but the meaning of the declaration:

```
B b(A());
// To get it working the way you expect [1]
B b = B(A());
// Or the slightly more obtuse.
B b((A()));
```

To the compiler is a function declaration. Google / search SO for the most-vexing-parse. More in the [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.21) including workarounds.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>: This is not *exactly* the same, as this requires an *implicit* conversion from `A` to `B`. If `B` was defined as:

```
class B {
  A a;
public:
  explicit B(const A& a_) : a(a_) {}
};
```

Then this would not be an alternative.

Answer (score 7):

```
B b(A());
```

You think this declares a variable? No.

It declares a function `b` whose return type is `B` and accepts a parameter of type `A (*)()` .

See this topic:

- [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

---

So if you want to declare a variable, put an extra braces around `A()` as:

```
B b((A())); //it declares an object
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of adding parenthesis use an equals sign: `B b = A();` is *almost* equivalent to `B b(( A() ));` (difference being present only if the `B(A)` constructor was explicit)

Comment: @David, why *almost*? Both are exactly same. I think `explicit` is not standard C++.

Comment: @iammilind: You can mark a constructor as explicit, and then it will not be used by implicit conversions. If `B` was declared as `struct B { explicit B( A const & ) {} };` then `B b(( A() ));` would work (code explicitly requests that constructor) while `B b = A();` would not because there is no implicit conversion from `A` to `B`. `B b = A();` is processed by the compiler as `B b = B(( A() ));` where the left hand side conversion is *implicit*.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
B b((A()));
```

your line is a function declaration. Unfortunately C allowed function declarations inside functions (which BTW seem pretty useless to me), so for backward compatibility reasons C++ allows this to. You can enforce variable definition with extra parentheses.